# OAuth 2.0 and Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm relatively new to programming and am having trouble with using OAuth with my app hosted on Amazon Beanstalk.

What I wish my app to do is to connect to the Constant Contact API, using the base code shown here

https://github.com/shannon7wallace/OAuth-2-PHP-Example

If I execute this code locally, everything works fine. I am able to login with my constant contact credentials and pull data. I was sure to setup my redirect uri in my constant contact developer key correctly, and everything works perfectly locally.

When I deployed it to AWS however, I would get a blank page when trying to navigate to index.php. I double checked my container settings and the zip package I uploaded to ensure I was pointing to the correct directories, and made sure my AWS healthcheck pointed to a publicly accessible URL (AWS shows app as being healthy), but the page is blank.

If I replace my index.php with simply HTML or even phpinfo(), it works. I suspect it gets hung up at the authentication check but even if I hard code my account credentials in and remove the login logic, I still get a blank page. Even the html outside my php script tags does not display, regardless if I include things like  or other head tags.

Googling for OAuth + Beanstalk produces very little, and the constantcontact API documentation, at least to my inexperienced eyes, is pretty sparse, but the closest thing I could find addressing my problem is this

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=277339&#277339

The scenario in the above thread seems to address a problem much more specific than mine, and I am unsure on how to apply the solution to my particular case.

Is there something obvious I am missing? I can't believe AWS would be unsuited for apps using OAuth considering the vast array of projects that are hosted on it.

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: EDIT: To those that are curious, I found the answer by manually enabling error reporting. Turns out the constant contact code tries to defined the OAuthException class, which will cause an error if your PHP install has OAuthException already defined. Removing the class eliminates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Beanstalk container options for PHP have an option to control whether errors should be displayed; switching it to `"On"` *should* write a fatal error on your page.

As it turns out, even after changing the setting, the pages would still be blank. I'm not sure if the feature is broken, but it definitely guards you from accidentally leaving it on :)

You'd have to log into your instance (assuming your site isn't loaded yet and it's really just one) and edit your code to insert the customary debug statements as high up as possible:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Barring any parse errors in your page, it will show the offending error.